# How to open a page in my browser smoothly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, safari, font-awesome

I am having a problem today in my browser.I make some web pages with bootstrap and fontawesome. it was working good till yesterday. But today i cannot open pages in my browser. it shows me connected to maxcdn and etc. I cannot open the pages with bootstrap & fontawesome.
others are working good. all browsers have the same problem.  how to fix this.

TIA

Comment: Do you get any errors when you open the pages ?

Comment: yes it wont open when i have internet connection on my pc and I want to open from my hdd.but when i have no internet connection it open very smoothly.